# How can I find out if I NEED openjdk-7-jre?

Tags: openjdk

I'm wondering what openjdk-7-jre is used for. Is there some app that requires it? If it's not being used by anything, I'd like to uninstall it.

Is there some commands I can run to learn how it is used (if it is used) on my system?

Answer (score 0):

I can tell you that Minecraft certainly uses it. It's basically just Java 7 for Ubuntu.

You could try `sudo apt-get purge openjdk-7-jre`, then do 'n' when it asks you if you want to remove it. It should list that and other packages that may use it. I'm not sure if you can actually use a command to see if the package is used by other packages, but really it's Java, and those programs can be regular .jar files sometimes.

You might have some programs that are .py that use Python. I once had an error while doing something in Terminal that was how Python outputs errors, but I don't think the program was specifically a Python program.

You could try searching Google for search commands, but I did `locate .jar` and got nice results.

Hope it helped :D

EDIT

```
scoutchorton@scoutcbuntu-pc:~$ sudo apt-get purge openjdk-8-jre
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  fastjar jarwrapper libcolorpicker-java libfontchooser-java
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  default-jre* javahelp2* logisim* openjdk-8-jre*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 4 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
After this operation, 8,779 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] n
Abort.
```

I have `openjde-8-jre`, but it's the same method. I have a simulator called logisim that I now know runs off Java. I won't post `locate .jar` results, because it would take up a lot of space.